# How to use chaining when using Lodash 3.0 modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

The following is an example node repl session:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/foo
$ cd /tmp/foo
$ npm install lodash
lodash@3.0.0 node_modules/lodash
$ node
> var chain = require('lodash/chain/chain')
> var map = require('lodash/collection/map')
> var value = require('lodash/chain/value')
> var fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry']
> chain(fruits)
{ __actions__: [],
  __chain__: true,
  __wrapped__: [ 'apple', 'banana', 'cherry' ] }
> value.call(chain(fruits))
[ 'apple', 'banana', 'cherry' ]
> var capitalize = require('lodash/string/capitalize')
> map(fruits, capitalize)
[ 'Apple', 'Banana', 'Cherry' ]
> map(chain(fruits), capitalize)
[ '',
  'True',
  'Apple,banana,cherry' ]
```

Ideally, I would have a map function that can receive a lodash chain object and return a lodash chain object so that I may utilize the new laziness of chaining in Lodash 3.0.  Something like this:

```
> value(map(chain(fruits)))
[ 'Apple', 'Banana', 'Cherry' ]
```

I understand that the following works as expected:

```
> var lodash = require('lodash')
> lodash(fruits).map(lodash.capitalize).value()
[ 'Apple', 'Banana', 'Cherry' ]
```

I would rather use modules and just require in what I will be using because I will be using this on a web client.

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: How can you benefit from the laziness of lodash chaining when using the modules?

Answer (score 2):

If you use modularized versions of lodash functions, they cannot know which other functions are loaded and available, so it wouldn't be easy to make it work out of the box.

What you can do however is to build your own custom build of lodash which will contain only the functions you need.

In your case it would be only:

```
lodash modern include=chain,value,map,capitalize
```

and then you're able to use it just like the normal version:

```
> var lodash = require('./lodash.custom.js')
> var fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry']
> lodash(fruits).map(lodash.capitalize).value()
[ 'Apple', 'Banana', 'Cherry' ]
```

while the js file is 5x smaller than the original one.